# How do I structure a project with separate concerns?

Tags: javascript, git

I am working on an app which I am building with React Native so with each new major update I build my app, then upload it to app stores, I also have a Express Server for the same which after every change I sync the code to my cloud droplet using git, As of now I have an "app" and a "server" folder in a single repo, now my question is should I have separate repos for both because while deploying my server code I cant just clone only the  server folder in the droplet, also I don't want to clone the whole repo even if only the server folder in required.

How do I approach this problem? a possible suggestion or fix

I have tried creating separate repos and it solves the problem, but then it becomes two repositories for the same project, Should I go with this separate repo structure?
As this is a personal project I am working on, it's a public repo, I also don't want people to explore or clone two different repos to understand / evaluate my code

Comment: the number of repos you use depends more on the workflow around application updates than anything else.  What you describe, an all at once deployment of new app and server versions, seems to assume compatibility of currently running versions and new/old server versions.  managing compatibilities between versions could be a reason to split the repos, but I would do that until you have a compelling reason.

Comment: @erik258, There's nothing like that, it's just the deployment process of the server code, if I put all of the code on a single repo, should I clone the whole repo on my server to get the server running?

Comment: you could use a github action or something to build artifacts and upload them if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can [set your app's source directory](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/how-to/deploy-from-monorepo/#deploy-using-monorepo-as-the-source) to deploy only one directory of a monorepo, without modifying your repo or using droplet disk space on other directories.